# Apex Charts height of sidebar

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, apexcharts

i am using the library `apexCharts` to build some charts in a project i`m working on.

This specific PieChart is loading the number of tries of a certain action, and it shows them in the side bar labels.

Recently i loaded a chart with a lot of tries and the container gained a scroll, i thought it would load all the tries, and by scrolling you would navigate throught them, but it doesn't show all of them..

[image: Label container]

I've been watching the responsive behaviour of the chart and in the 1300px > resolution size, it does show all the labels through the scroll.

these are the options of my apex chart code:

```
chartOptions: {
  chart: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 390,
      type: 'pie',
      toolbar: {
          show: true
      }
  },
  labels: chartData.labels,
  legend: {
      markers: {
          width: 26,
          height: 12,
          radius: 8,
      },
      position: chartOptions.legendPosition || "right",
  },
  theme: {
      monochrome: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#537F23',
      }
  },
  title: {
      text: chartOptions.title,
      margin: 10,
      style: {
          fontSize:  chartOptions.titleSize || '25px',
          fontWeight:  'bold',
          color:  '#707070'
      },
  },
  responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1400,
        options: {
              chart: {
                  width: '90%',
                  height: 417,
              },

        }
      }, {
          breakpoint: 800,
          options: {
              chart: {
                  height: 400,
              },
              legend: {
                  position: "bottom",
                  horizontalAlign: 'left',
              }
          }
      },
```

I tried to play around with the chart height, to no use. I think this may be a lib error.

Sugestions ?

thanks .